# How can I automate the testing of flash games?

Tags: automated-testing

If **I want to automate testing of flash games** like car race, bike race bubbleshooter, video slot games or video poker.  Is there any open source automation testing tool available for this purpose.  **I am a fresher for game testing.**

Comment: This may help: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=flash

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).  It is based on using screenshot images and works with flash.  I've played with it and think its quite cool, but I've never used it at work.  There is a nice article about using it and setup [here](http://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/using-sikuli-to-test-legacy-flash/).

Comment: The only problem with it, that it does not exclude transparent pixels. According to the devs the 2.0 will contain that feature, but it comes out in 2017 oct or later. :S

Answer (score 0):

We are workng with the ranorex and eggplant, they are really good solutions

http://www.ranorex.com/

http://www.testplant.com/eggplant/testing-tools/

Comment: Could you please update your answer to say what aspects of Ranorex and Eggplant are most helpful for new game testers wanting to automate flash game testing. That would make your answer much more helpful to the poster.